# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp, mariadb

Estoy ingresando datos desde php, he cambiado la consulta varias veces pero el error es el mismo, es mas activo el log de mysql, maria db y la consulta se realiza y se inserta en la base de datos, no se que mas puedo revisar,
mi codigo php es:

```
$covid = conectarSeguimiento();
//Preparar query
$grabarSeguimiento="insert into seguimiento(seg_sintomas,seg_fInicioSintomas,seg_tipoRiesgo,seg_tomaHispoado,seg_fTomaHisopado,seg_resulHisopado,seg_fResulHisopado,seg_incapacidad,seg_fIniIncapacidad,seg_ffinIncapacidad,seg_diasIncapacidad,seg_aislamiento,seg_fIniAislamiento,seg_ffinAislamiento,seg_diasAislamiento,seg_fMedLaboral,seg_fReintegro,seg_trabCasa,seg_recomen,seg_observ,seg_persContacto,seg_fUltimoCont,seg_diasContacto,seg_aerosoles,seg_fUltimoSeg,seg_fProximoSeg,seg_fk_servicio,seg_fk_turno,seg_fk_estPrincipal,seg_fk_estSecundario,seg_fcierreARL,seg_reporte,seg_estadoCaso) VALUES
                ('".$_POST["sintomas"]."','".$_POST["fIniSin"]."','".$_POST["tipoRiesgo"]."','".$_POST["tomHiso"]."','".$_POST["fecHiso"]."','".$_POST["resHiso"]."',
                '".$_POST["fecResHiso"]."','".$_POST["incap"]."','".$_POST["fecInInc"]."','".$_POST["fecFiInc"]."','".$_POST["diaInc"]."','".$_POST["aisl"]."',
                '".$_POST["fecInAis"]."','".$_POST["fecFiAis"]."','".$_POST["diaAis"]."','".$_POST["fecMedLab"]."','".$_POST["fecReint"]."','".$_POST["traCas"]."',
                '".$_POST["recom"]."','".$_POST["obsv"]."','".$_POST["perCont"]."','".$_POST["ultCont"]."','".$_POST["diaPos"]."','".$_POST["actAer"]."','".$_POST["ultSeg"]."',
                '".$_POST["proxSeg"]."','".$_POST["servicio"]."','".$_POST["turno"]."','".$_POST["estadoPrincip"]."','".$_POST["estSecundario"]."','".$_POST["cierARL"]."',
                '".$_POST["repor"]."','".$estCaso."')";
//Envia el query
$grabSegui = $covid->query($grabarSeguimiento);
//Validacion de que si se guardo el seguimiento
if ($covid->query($grabSegui) == TRUE) {
echo "<script>alert('Seguimiento Creado Exitosamente!')
window.location.href='../vista/administracion_clientes.php';
</script>";
mysqli_free_result($covid);
} else {
        echo $covid->error;
        echo $grabSegui;
        echo "<script>alert('Error al grabar el seguimiento.$grabarSeguimiento.')";
}
cerrarSeguimeinto($covid);
```

en el log de mariadb me retorna:

```
201123 20:58:49    23 Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on seguimientocovid
       23 Query SET NAMES utf8
       23 Query insert into seguimiento(seg_sintomas,seg_fInicioSintomas,seg_tipoRiesgo,seg_tomaHispoado,seg_fTomaHisopado,seg_resulHisopado,seg_fResulHisopado,seg_incapacidad,seg_fIniIncapacidad,seg_ffinIncapacidad,seg_diasIncapacidad,seg_aislamiento,seg_fIniAislamiento,seg_ffinAislamiento,seg_diasAislamiento,seg_fMedLaboral,seg_fReintegro,seg_trabCasa,seg_recomen,seg_observ,seg_persContacto,seg_fUltimoCont,seg_diasContacto,seg_aerosoles,seg_fUltimoSeg,seg_fProximoSeg,seg_fk_servicio,seg_fk_turno,seg_fk_estPrincipal,seg_fk_estSecundario,seg_fcierreARL,seg_reporte,seg_estadoCaso) VALUES
                ('SI','2020-09-02','BAJO','EPS','2020-09-02','POSITIVO',
                '2020-09-02','SI','2020-09-02','2020-09-04','3','SI',
                '2020-09-02','2020-09-04','3','2020-09-04','2020-09-04','NO',
                'NO','prueba','qwer','2020-09-08','22','wwwwwww','2020-09-02',
                '2021-02-02','3','2','3','7','2021-02-02',
                'OTRA EMPRESA','F')
       23 Query 1
       23 Quit
```

pero sigue saliendo:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 11
no importa como cambie la consulta, lo peor es que si ingresa los valores
me toca trabajar con xamp 3.2.2
ya estoy desesperado
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de mucho validar he encontrado el error, tal vez pueda servir a los que tengan la misma duda, el error esta en esta linea

```
//Envia el query
$grabSegui = $covid->query($grabarSeguimiento);
//Validacion de que si se guardo el seguimiento
if ($covid->query($grabSegui) == TRUE) {
```

LA linea $grabSegui = $covid->query($grabarSeguimiento); esta enviando la consulta y al ser un insert la ejecuta, pero en el if se envia de nuevo la consulta, es una redundancia, por eso no importa como cambien la consulta siempre estara el error en la misma posicion, ojala le sirva a alguien